# What To Cover Hole With

Tags: plumbing, ventilation, cover

I had a room remodeled and added a sink, the pipe that connects to the sewage line for drainage runs straight up into the wall and my drywall guy said to call a plumber to get them to add the appropriate covering for the hole.  Drywall guy said it had to be something specific to allow proper ventilation and be up to code.  Plumber quoted me $150 just to come out and look at it...I'm thinking it can't be to difficult (and probably pretty standard) vent/cover to add to it.

This is an image of what I've got - what do I need to purchase to cover that hole?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

The only real question is whether this has to be covered in an *accessible* way or if it actually has to provide *ventilation*. I really hope it is not to provide ventilation, because if so you are venting plumbing system into your living area. Assuming it is only for *access* (i.e., for future maintenance/repairs) then there are inexpensive access panels [such as this one](https://amzn.to/3Kfikjt):

[image: Fluidmaster cover]

There are many different brands. I first learned about this type of product from a Home RenoVision YouTube video, but unfortunately I can't find the right video at the moment. But basically you expand your hole to the right size for the cover and it just snaps into place.

Comment: since it's the drain line for a sink, would venting into the laundry room be a big issue?

Comment: While working the venting should be only inwards, and the normal tolerances of an access door/panel should allow adequate air to move inwards. When the mechanical vent fails, there will be a stink going the other direction, and you'll replace it. If not obvious, I hate mechanical vents, and will go to considerable effort to install a vent pipe instead...

Answer (score 1):

Since what you are showing a picture of is a mechanical vent, you need an access door or access panel, because mechanical vents need to be able to replaced when they fail (as they do.)

They come in many sizes and are widely available.

Comment: any one you recommend?  Just so I know I'm getting the right thing, haha

Comment: Recommendations are specifically off topic here. The access doors are not anything special, unless it's a firewall - go ask at your hardware store if you still have one, or buy one online, or even at the orange or blue boxes.